# SQL Injection in an Update clause SQLite engine - Affect other tables?

Tags: sql-injection

I have an SQL Injection in an *update* SQL query that is run against an SQLite database in it's default configuration. The query itself is somewhat similar to the following:

```
"UPDATE user SET active = 1 WHERE name = " + attacker_supplied_string
```

Although I initially assumed it'll be doable, I now face the fact that due to the limited nature of SQLite such a bug is impossible to exploit: Not only I cannot get a shell out of it, I've also failed turning this SQL injection to a more flexible database manipulation. I cannot seem to be able to manipulate that query to a query that'll cause an insertion (or update of a different table).

**What I've tried**

1. Stacked queries - disabled.
2. `load_extension` - disabled.
3. Subqueries - the `returning` syntax is only partially implemented in SQLite. More specifically, it's only implemented for select queries (and not updates). I cannot think of another way of nesting an update or insert here.
4. Blind SQL injection - Queries are executed in a dedicated thread and don't return a response. Timing queries to extract information seems improbable and quite difficult to implement. Additionally, there isn't a lot of information worth extracting in this use case.
5. SQLite engine bugs? I've spent only a short while but couldn't find a CVE that might be exploitable in this context.

Additionally, modifying the table in question (`user` in the example above) is unfortunately useless to me. The table isn't really called that and has no meaningful data in it. I'm looking for ways to modify anything outside the queried table.

Before giving up, I thought it's worth it to ask around and see if someone else can come up with a possible approach.

Comment: When the attacker_supplied_string is something like "John OR 1=1" it would set *every* user active. That may be bad enough.

Comment: "cannot be exploited" -- yes it can be exploited, but you want to do something ***specific*** like returning a shell. That requires a specific vulnerability. So, I would rephrase the question and reframe your goal here.

Comment: @schroeder I don't want specifically a shell, as I've mentioned in my question. I want something that _carries an effect_. Unfortunately, I have failed to find something that has any significant effect, as I've described under "what i've tried"

Comment: @Jeff Yes. Unfortunately that side-effect is quite meaningless since the table does not list users (or anything else that'll have any considerable effect when modifying). Thank you both for taking the time and reading, tho!

Comment: It sounds like you would need access to the database to see what effect you are having.

Comment: @schroeder I'm not sure I follow. For the record, I have a testing environment in which I have access to the DB and can see it's structure and entries. I'm searching for the SQL syntax / construct that will let me turn an `update` query to an `insert` query, for example.